# Prove $|\sqrt[n]{a}-\sqrt[n]{b}|\le\sqrt[n]{|a-b|}$

Tags: inequality

$n\geq2$ be an integer

Prove $|\sqrt[n]{a}-\sqrt[n]{b}|\le\sqrt[n]{|a-b|}$ for all $a,b\geq0$

I try taking both side n squared and using binomial theorem, but I can't prove it.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but I think $x$ and $y$ should be $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2992987/42969

Comment: Please flag as a duplicate: [How do you prove the follwing $|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}| \le \sqrt[n]{|x-y|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992987/how-do-you-prove-the-follwing-sqrtnx-sqrtny-le-sqrtnx-y)

Comment: Thanks. I should have searched variant x,y not a, b