# Inequality $|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}|\le \sqrt[n]{C_n|x-y|}$ for odd $n$

Tags: inequality

I'm interested in a simple way to estimate $|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}|$ from $|x-y|$.

For $n=2$ and $n=3$, we have $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\le \sqrt{x-y}$ for $x,y\ge 0$ and $|\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{y}|\le \sqrt[3]{4(x-y)}$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

When $n$ is even, $|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}|\le \sqrt[n]{|x-y|}$ holds since $x,y$ are nonnegative.

My question is: for an arbitrary odd number $n$, is there a constant $C_n$ such that $$|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}|\le \sqrt[n]{C_n|x-y|}$$
for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2992987/42969

Comment: ... reading that thread again I realize that it is for nonnegative $x, y$ only.

Comment: Anyway $x^{1/n}$ is not always defined as  a real number.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Defining $x^{1/n}$ for *odd* $n$ and real $x$ as the inverse function of $x^n$ is a common definition, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that OP was taking $n$ odd. $n=2$ also appears in the question! @MartinR

Comment: Indeed, the $n=2$ example is misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x, y$ be real numbers and $n$ an *odd* integer.

If $x$ and $y$ have the same sign then
$$
 |\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}|\le \sqrt[n]{|x-y|} \, ,
$$
see for example [proving that $f(x) = x^s$ is holder continuous with holder exponent s](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2070706/42969) or [How do you prove the follwing $|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}| \le \sqrt[n]{|x-y|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2992987/42969).

And if $x < 0 < y$ then, proceeding as in [Prove a function is Hölder continuous but not Lipschitz continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213179/prove-a-function-is-h%C3%B6lder-continuous-but-not-lipschitz-continuous),
$$
 \left( \frac{|x|}{|x| + y}\right)^{1/n} + \left( \frac{y}{|x| + y}\right)^{1/n} 
\le \max \{ u^{1/n} + (1-u)^{1/n} \mid 0 < u < 1 \} = 2^{(n-1)/n} 
$$
so that
$$
 \sqrt[n]{y}-\sqrt[n]{x} = |x|^{1/n} + y^{1/n} 
\le 2^{(n-1)/n} (|x| + y)^{1/n} =  2^{(n-1)/n}\sqrt[n]{y-x} \, .
$$

Therefore
$$
|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}|\le \sqrt[n]{2^{n-1}|x-y|}
$$
for all $x, y \in \Bbb R$ and odd integers $n$. Choosing $x=-y \ne 0$ shows that $C_n = 2^{n-1}$ is the best possible constant.